# raspberry pi model B+/ install eCos

Tags: sd-card, software-installation

I have a raspberry pi model B+. I have to install **eCos** rtos on it. I can't find a solution. Can someone help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the Raspberry Pi's are listed in the [ECOS supported hardware list](http://ecos.sourceware.org/hardware.html). And by that I mean you are probably out of luck. To get ECOS running on the ARM11, you will need to [port it](http://ecos.sourceware.org/fom-serv/ecos/cache/39.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well it's seems possible nowadays, you can register for Developer's Kits

https://www.ecoscentric.com/rpi/index.shtml

Can't find much info though. Not sure if it's [vaporware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaporware)

Maybe somebody can share some experiences?